# CMake system environment variable expansion

Tags: cmake

Using CMake I try to expand environment variable values in custom file.
I do the following

```
configure_file(config.cnf.in config.cnf)
```

I do not use @ONLY attribute.

`config.cnf.in` content:

```
[options]
some_value1 = @VAR_FROM_CMAKE@   // ok
some_value2 = ${SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}  // empty result
some_value2 = ${VAR_FROM_CMAKE}  // ok -- from CMake?!
```

`@VAR_FROM_CMAKE@` is expanded successfully, but
`${SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}` is not - empty value.

I confused - `@VAR@` and `${VAR}` - are leading only to the CMAKE variables, but not to system env?

**So my question is:**
Is it possible to expand system env variables in the custom file using CMake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not evaluating the system variable correctly: the correct command is `$ENV{SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}` (have a look here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/ENV.html)

```
[options]
some_value1 = @VAR_FROM_CMAKE@
some_value2 = $ENV{SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}
some_value2 = ${VAR_FROM_CMAKE}
```

Comment: It works, but only with one remark - 'env' should be capitalized:
some_value2 = $ENV{SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlexandrDerkach you are right, I'll edit the answer

Comment: I have one more question - is it possible to set a default value for this env variable ? like this:
$ENV{SYS_ENV_VAR:-defaultValue}

Comment: @AlexandrDerkach Yes, it is possible using a cmake variable as container. I can't post an example here, would you like to post a new question?

Comment: Yes, I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723221/cmake-expand-env-variable-with-default-value-for-custom-file
thanks in advance!