# CMake expand env variable with default value for custom file

Tags: cmake

Using CMake I'm trying to expand system environment variable values in custom file. 
I do the following command:

```
configure_file(config.cnf.in config.cnf)
```

**config.cnf.in** content:

```
[options]
some_value1 = $ENV{SYSTEM_ENV_VAR}
```

**The question is:**
Is it possible to set the **default** value for **SYSTEM_ENV_VAR** variable, if it is not defined?

I tried to do this:

```
   some_value1 = $ENV{SYSTEM_ENV_VAR:-defaultValue}
```

and got an cmake error:
Invalid character (':') in a variable name: 'SYSTEM_ENV_VAR'

I didn't find the answer in the docs:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/configure_file.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a default value for the variable, but you can store the environment variable inside a normal cmake variable, and if it was not set define a default value.
I tested this:

```
set(EXIST $ENV{HOME})
set(NOT_EXIST $ENV{NOT_EXIST})

if(EXIST)
    message("Variable EXIST exist")
else()
    message("Variable EXIST DOES NOT exist, setting default value")
    set(EXIST "Default value")
endif()

if(NOT_EXIST)
    message("Variable NOT_EXIST exist")
else()
    message("Variable NOT_EXIST DOES NOT exist, setting default value")
    set(NOT_EXIST "Default value")
endif()

message ("EXIST: ${EXIST}")
message ("NOT_EXIST: ${NOT_EXIST}")
```

My output for this is

```
Variable EXIST exist
Variable NOT_EXIST DOES NOT exist, setting default value
EXIST: /home/user
NOT_EXIST: Default value
```

Comment: thanks, this workaround should work. But I still want to find a better solution, because there can be a lot of variables, I don't want to put them all in CMakeLists file.
Maybe try to call a custom python script to expand variables with default values..

Comment: @AlexandrDerkach I made a complete example to show how everything works, but in the end is just a variable and a if, something you do in a couple of lines. An external script is something much more complex, you have to define a new command, set dependencies...
If you want you can even script everything inside a function